# double doubt working with fourier inverse theorem and a calculation of a sup

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, fourier-analysis

the first one is this :

I am working with Fourier inverse theorem and I have $f(t)=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int\left(\int f(u) e^{-i \omega u} d u\right) e^{i \omega t} d \omega$ with $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$
the book says I can't swap the integral because $f(u) e^{i \omega(t-u)}$ is not in $L^1(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R})$ but why ? mabe because \begin{aligned}
& \left|f(u) e^{i \omega(t-u)}\right|=|f(u)| \\
& \iint|f(u)|=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} c \stackrel{?}{=} \infty
\end{aligned}

and the second one is this : How can I find $\sup _{n \in R}\left|\frac{e^{-i n}-1}{n}\right|$? How can I show this is finite ?

I have to do derivatie of complex exponential as usual ? but calculations are very bad

Comment: For the first question, if $c=0$, the integral is $0$, but if $c>0$, then it is obviously infinite (whats the area under an infinitely long rectangle of positive height?) Second, use the MVT on the complex exponential to see the supremum is at most $1$. In fact the limit as $n\to 0$ is equal to derivative at the origin if the complex exponential. The limit at infinity is $0$ since the numerator is bounded by $2$ and the denominator blows up.

Comment: @peek-a-boo so the first one is correct? or how can be formalized better?